# TensorFlow: tf.Session.run() fetches and execution dependencies

Tags: tensorflow

I have typical/generic TF (r1.3) configuration where reading a single tf.record file and decoding the result to query some record values:

```py
import os, tensorflow as tf

# path to TF record file containing single record
record_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'tf.record')

# init a finite file queue with num_epochs=1
file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([record_file_path],name='file_queue',num_epochs=1)

# init record reader
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

# read the record file
_, tfrecord_read_op = reader.read(file_queue)

tfrecord = tf.parse_single_example(
    tfrecord_read_op,
    features={
        'image/height' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64 ),
        'image/width'  : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64 ),
        'image/label'  : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64 ),
        'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    },
    name='features'
)

# since exported as tf.int64 there is no need for tf.decode_raw
heightT = tfrecord['image/height']
widthT  = tfrecord['image/width' ]

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # init vars
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer ())

    # Start populating the filename queue
    queue_coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
    queue_worker_threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=queue_coordinator)

    # kaboom!
    height = sess.run(heightT)
    width  = sess.run(widthT )

    # why does this work ??
    #height, width = sess.run([heightT, widthT])

    # close down the queue
    queue_coordinator.request_stop()
    queue_coordinator.join(queue_worker_threads)

print('image height x width : {}x{}'.format(height,width))
```

Note that the file queue is clamped at `num_epochs=1` so will only produce the single file for the `TFRecordReader` exactly one time.

In the compute graph, both `heightT` and `widthT` tensors-ops depend on `tfrecord` which depends on `tfrecord_read_op`

Therefore, any time that `tfrecord` is evaluated, the compute graph dependencies should invoke another dequeue from the `file_queue`.  This is indeed the case when evaluating `heightT` and `widthT` in *separate* `tf.Session` `run()` calls.

A an aside, if `num_epoch=None` (i.e. infinite dequeue for the single file) the separate calls will succeed (!?) And, `num_epochs=None` is the default.

Now, finally, the question:  **how/why is a single `run()` call with multiple fetches successful in evaluating both tensor-ops?  That is, why is**

```py
height,width = sess.run([heightT,widthT])
```

**successful but**

```py
height = sess.run(heightT)
width  = sess.run(widthT )
```

**fails?**

Indeed, using a placeholder (dtype=tf.string) to hold the result of tfrecord_read_op and performing `tf.parse_single_example` on the placeholder mitigates this effect but does not really shed any light on what is happening in the graph evaluation for the case(s) highlighted above.

Comment: For your final question -- if you fetch height/width in a single run call, it will reuse any shared tensors (ie, single queue dequeue). In 2 calls, it will trigger 2 dequeues

Comment: So then no op is evaluated more than once per session.run call?  In graph traversal sense, the op gets marked as evaluated/seen and if encounter that same op/node while evaluating another fetch within the same run call, the op will not be re-evaluated.  This is more obvious if there is a cycle in the compute graph but less clear for things like shared file readers.  Likely the simplest demonstration of reuse would then be something like `out1,out2=sess.run([op,op])` only evaluates `op` once for `out1` and reuses the result for `out2`.

Answer (score 0):

When running `height,width = sess.run([heightT,widthT])` TensorFlow will calculate the dependency for `heightT, widthT`, get an op that will calculate both these two `Tensor`s in one shot. Then `Session` run this op and store the calculated results then fetch them.